# Migrations adiciona a letra S no nome da tabela

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migrations

Tenho um model:

```
public class pimentel
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cod_item_Crm { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string data_anal { get; set; }
    public string modelo { get; set; }
    public int cod_cli { get; set; }
}
```

Porém, quando executo a aplicação, o sistema, sempre procura a tabela de nome `pimentels`, e caso nao exista, ele cria uma tabela, mas, sempre com a letra "S" no final.

Posso mudar o do `model` para qualquer outro, e sempre ele gera com a letra "S" no final

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aguem tem noção oque pode ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É a regra padrão de pluralização do nome das classes.

Você pode desabilitar isto no método `OnModelCreating`, com o seguinte código

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```